# How can i sum hours of same date in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, sum

I'm making a macro that sum some hours in a range of date. I have a little problem.. This is a structure

```
14/10/2013   PLUTO  5,00    
14/10/2013   PLUTO  3,00    
15/10/2013   PLUTO  8,00
```

every day must have 8,00 hours. The problem is that in some case i can find the same date, like 14/10/2013, and in this case i have to sum it's hours so 5.00 + 3.00. How can i sum the hours of same dates?

I need this because then i'll do some controls and if the day has less or more of 8.00 hours i'll write it in a log file otherwise nope. Thanks and hope you understand the question

Comment: is the list sorted by date, i.e. will times to be added always be beneath each other?

Comment: Yes the sames dates are always near each other.

Comment: It looks like you're working with an employee hours log, so you want to ensure that the employee is working 8 hours each day, correct? If so, that can change how we help you.

Comment: yes it is correct. It's what i want. Check the 8 hours every day. But a an employee could write something like i've written above

Answer (score 3):

Easiest would be to create a Pivot table with date and planetname fields as row labels, and hour field as value field (sum).

[image]

Comment: nope ... just "Insert" "Pivot Table" :-) ... you can of course have more planets, and for Pivot tables, you don't need a particular sort order.

Comment: Hi @MikeD i'm trying to use the pivot table.. It's perfect but i need something more automathic. I'm creating the macro because i can do what i need in a faster way. What i need right now is understand how sum the value in hour column if the date is same. And it's exactly what the pivot table do! But i need do it with my macro. Understand?

Comment: there are ca. 100 ways to do it ... please be more specific how you want to aggregate ... e.g. display total next to last data record / compress to single sum per user / extract sum to new range/sheet / create Pivot by VBA, etc. ... and start to show some code which we can help on ;)